# Creating thermometer chart in R

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to create a thermometer plot in R. I couldn't find any examples for thermometer plot. Could anyone show me how this can be implemented in R ?

This graph will be used to show the amount of fund raised during an event. An example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `?symbols`

```
# fundraising objective
z <- 1000
# amount gathered
y <- 600 

symbols(1, thermometers = cbind(.5, 1, y/z), fg = 2, 
        xlab = NA, ylab = NA, axes = F, main = "Fundraising event")
text(1, paste0(y, "$", " / ", z, "$"), pos = 2, offset = 3)
text(1, paste0(y/z*100, "%"), pos = 1, offset = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Steven, thank you for the solution and it looks very close to what I am looking for. Is it possible to increase the size of the thermometer ?

Comment: @Jdbaba From `?symbols`: *The first two columns give the width and height of the thermometer symbols*